# Forcing a rounding mode for a single operation in OpenCL

Tags: floating-point, opencl, rounding, cross-language

Suppose I want to perform a (single-precision) division of `x` by `y` in my CUDA kernel, and regardless of anything else, get a rounded-up result (= rounded to positive infinity). This is easy: Instead of:

```
float r = x / y;
```

I write :

```
float r = __fdiv_ru(x, y);
```

and I could do the same for `rn` (round nearest), `rd` etc.

How do I do the same thing in OpenCL?

If I look at the [documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/3.0/docs/man/html/) for math functions (OpenCL 3.0), I find only find `native_divide`, and am told that:

> The built-in math functions are not affected by the prevailing rounding mode in the calling environment, and always return the same value as they would if called with the **round to nearest even** rounding mode.

so, ,that's not the way to go. What *do* I do?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/html/OpenCL_Ext.html#cl_khr_select_fprounding_mode), there's an extension which allows us to do this.

with the extension enabled, this should work:

```
#pragma OPENCL SELECT_ROUNDING_MODE rtp
float r = x / y;
```

(here, "rtp" stands for rounding to positive infinity = rounding up.)

Unfortunately, the extension is deprecated and I'm not sure we can "trust" this approach. It also apparently involves some sort of macro trickery.

Comment: Check your results and ensure this produces the desired result. I've tried this in the past and been disappointed. My compiler ignored my pragma and did it's own thing. I ended up condemned to inline assembly with PTX (lookup "PTX Inline Assembly" the CUDA syntax works in OpenCL).